# How to create a button on the Fly in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Normally if you create a Button in C# you do this:

`Button button = new Button()`

What I want to do is that I can add a button on the fly, and that the name String that the method gets is the name of the Button.

```
    private void CreateButton(String name, String text, int x, int y, int sizeX, int sizeY)
    {
        Button name (converted to Button) = new Button();
        name.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
        name.Text = text;
        name.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        name.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(sizeX, sizeY);
        name.TabIndex = 1;
        name.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        name.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.name_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(name);
    }
```

How can I do that. How to handle the events, is the next step, but not for now.

Answer (score 2):

The *variable* name of the button is not relevant. You can call it `b` if you like.

Set the `Name` property if you want to be able to find it by name later:

```
private void CreateButton(String name, String text, int x, int y, int sizeX, int sizeY)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Name = name;

    // ...

    this.Controls.Add(b);
}
```

As for your event: you can't generate an event per button (unless you start using reflection but no), but you can register one event handler for all buttons:

```
b.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DynamicButton_Click);
```

Then implement that:

```
private void DynamicButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var button is sender as Button;

    if (button == null) throw new ArgumentException();

    if (button.Name == "Button1")
    {
        // do stuff for Button1
    }
}
```